# Mysql Left Join Not working As Expected

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am attempting a simple left join that is giving me problems. I need all the customers listed (table a) regardless of whether or not they have an invoice (table b) between a certain date range.  Both of my attempts have yielded the only customer that has an invoice for that period:

```
select b.clientname,a.* from invdata a
   left join clidata b on a.clidataid=b.recordid
      where b.recstatus=1 and b.isactive=1
      and a.reccreate between '2015-04-01 00:00:00' and '2015-04-30 23:59:59';
```

OR

```
select a.clientname,b.* from clidata a
   left join invdata b on a.recordid=b.clidataid
      where a.recstatus=1 and a.isactive=1
      and b.reccreate between '2015-04-01 00:00:00' and '2015-04-30 23:59:59';
```

Little help, please.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join with where condition is inner join and will filter the data as per the where condition, you may need to move the where condition into joining condition

```
  select b.clientname,a.* from invdata a
  left join clidata b on a.clidataid=b.recordid
  and b.recstatus=1 and b.isactive=1
  and a.reccreate between '2015-04-01 00:00:00' and '2015-04-30 23:59:59';
```

Comment: Wow.  What a rookie mistake.  Thanks Abhik!